# Why do I need to activate my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios

This is something I don't particularly understand. I get that for Windows, activation exists to prevent software piracy, but you don't have to pay for iOS. Perhaps activation exists to prevent Android devices from using iOS or to prevent jailbreaks and downgrades? Anyone know the real reason why?

Answer (score 2):

Activation in the sense of iPhone, or any cellular phone, for that matter, is registering and provisioning that phone for use with your cellular carrier. (Or more specifically for GSM networks, provisioning the SIM card.) It is unrelated to the type of activation found in Windows and other software.

It basically registers your phone with the carrier and obtains your specific settings (phone number, etc).

Comment: Makes sense, but then why does the iPhone need to be connected to Apple's servers? I also know the iPod Touch needs to be activated too, and that device has no phone features.

Comment: I am not sure why iPod touch requires activation but for iPhone I believe it is to make it a smoother process for the consumer, since many functions require an Apple ID.